# Cannot send a POST request in HTML Form

Tags: html, node.js, web, request

So I am serving this particular HTML file from my NodeJS server which is getting rendered properly. But the issue is that when I click on the CREATE button, I am not being able to send a POST request to my server. I am getting the page rendered on a GET request. But when I click on POST. I want to send a POST request back to my server. Please help me sort this.

```
    <section>
        <form action="/login" method="POST"></form>
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 bg-light p-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label col-label" for="old_pass">First Name</label>
                            <input class="field__input" type="text" name="old_pass" placeholder="" id="old_pass">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label col-label" for="new_pass">Last Name</label>
                            <input class="field__input" type="text" name="new_pass" placeholder="" id="new_pass">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label col-label my-3" for="emailaddress_personal;">Email Address</label>
                            <input class="field__input" type="text" name="emailaddress_personal;" placeholder="joe.black@gmail.com" id="emailaddress_personal;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label col-label" for="chk_new_pass">Password </label>
                            <input class="field__input" type="password" name="chk_new_pass" placeholder="" id="chk_new_pass">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Create</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: Does the server have a POST route configured? If yes, do you see any errors there?

Comment: It does have POST routes registered.

Comment: Nothing is happening whenever I am clicking the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nothing is happening whenever I am clicking the button.

You have two problems.

## You don't have a button.

> ```
> <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Create</a>
> ```

You have an anchor (which is missing both the `href` and `name` attributes) which is styled to look like a button.

CSS does not replace semantic HTML, especially when the semantics of that HTML have specific functionality that you need.

A submit button uses the `button` or `input` elements.

```
<button>Label</button>

<input type="submit" value="Label and value">
```

## Nothing is inside your form

> ```
> <form action="/login" method="POST"></form>
> ```

The end tag for your form is immediately after the start tag, so none of your form controls are inside it.

You have a second end tag later that is ignored (because the form is already closed).

Remove the first end tag.

Comment: Yes. Thank You. It was sooo stupid of me. An autocomplete tag thing. Thanks alot! Couldn't believe after hours of effort it all came down to this.

Comment: Sorry a noobie here. Even though now the request is getting parsed. I cannot get the form values in the request. Is there any way I can get them in the request??

Comment: They should be in the request if you do what I said. If you can’t read them it might be a problem with your server-side code.

Answer (score -1):

I think a tag not support submit. Can you try input type submit

Comment: I changed the a tag to ```<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >``` still no luck. Though I got the same UI, but nothing happened upon submitting.

Comment: Because submit button not inside form. Form tag opening and closing and its empty.

Answer (score -1):

You said you were getting a page rendered on a GET request, you may want to prevent the rendering the page by creating a function inside an `onsubmit` attribute of the `<form>` tag, and add it like:

```js
function onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Make your post request here using axios / AJAX or etc..
}
```

If error still persist, try debugging your post route on your nodejs server.